# Don't understand how the table can be made more compact

Tags: tables

**Warning:** I am new to `LaTeX` markup and this whole thingy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \caption{Comparisons}\label{tab1}\small\\
    \hline\rowcolor{Black}
    Column & Column & Column & Column & 
    Column & Column & Column \\ \hline  
    \raggedright Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & \\ \hline
    \raggedright Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & \\ \hline
    \raggedright Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

*How can this possibly become more compact, easier to modify, repeated sizes,
white color on column text, a bit of centering inside the cells.*

```
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{%
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{%
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%
```

**or**,

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

**My desired end result, except: Black background, borders, and white column text.**
[image]

Comment: use `c` rather than  `p{2cm}` so the column is the natural width of the content? You can simply the markup for repeated columns by `*{6}{p{2cm}` or `*{6}{c}`  for 6 columns with a p or c type

Comment: `\small\\ `  the scope of `\small` ends at the `\\ ` so it makes no text small, if you want the whole table small put `\small` before `begin{longtable}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, wow, I didn't know this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Erh, then better use {\small \begin{longtable} .... \end{longtable} }` or the rest of the document is in small. Alternative load `array` and inject `\small` into each column via `*{6}{>{\small}p{2cm}}` or similar.

Comment: @daleif, I don't fully understand how you mean.

Comment: Why are you using `longtable`? Do you want a table that spans multiple pages? Your desired table image doesn't seem to span multiple pages.

Comment: @Imran, because, in case I add more, I want it to continue on the next page and not break.

Comment: unrelated but remove all of `\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm`  You set the page size later using the  `geometry` package which over-writes all these settings

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, why?

Comment: because setting them to one thing using a non-latex tex-primitive assignment then setting them to something else using the latex geometry package  just makes your document look complicated for no reason.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks. What about the column color? How do I color it white once, and apply that to all of the columns at the top?

Comment: put \color{white}  in each cell (there is no scope that just covers a table row)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Isn't there a more efficient way? Declare once and it magically puts that into every column cell at the top. Currently, `\rowcolor{Black}` colors the background to black on every row at the top.

Comment: I know what `\rowcolor` does (I wrote it) you can not do the same with the font color.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, wow, you are the original author of the `rowcolor`, **cool**!

Comment: if you write `\small\begin{longtable} ... \end{longtable} text` then `text` is also in `\small` font.

Comment: @AlbinM You will find many TeX gurus /TeXnician/TeXperts here. [This is a list of the package maintainers who are/were active in this group](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1181/219947).

Comment: @Imran, **Cool** list, thank you so much for sharing this.

Comment: Please provide code for the table which you show as desired result. It is not clear what you like to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not very clear (to me) what you after, so I guess that you may be interested for the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\NewTblrTheme{fancy caption}%
{
\SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{\small\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries}
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwohline}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {4} {2} { \l_tblr_childs_total_tl }
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{dingbat}
\newcommand\gcm{\textcolor{teal}{\checkmark}}% GreenCheckMark

\begin{document}
    \begin{talltblr}[
  theme = fancy caption,
caption = {Table caption},
  label = {tab:talltblr}
                    ]{hline{eachtwohline} = {dashed, 0.1pt},
                      colspec = {Q[l,m, wd=33mm] 
                                 *{6}{Q[c,m]}},
                       colsep = 4pt,
                       rowsep = 1pt,  
                     hline{Z} = 1pt,
                         rows = {font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                       row{1} = {fg=white, bg=black!80},
                     }
Head    & {first\\second}   
                & {first\\second}   
                        & {first\\second} 
                                & {first\\second}   
                                        & {first\\second}   
                                                & {first\\second}
                                                        \\
DAO attack   
        &       & \gcm  &       &       &       &       \\
Attack on wallet software
        &       & \gcm  & \gcm  &       & \gcm  &       \\
Criminal Activity
        &       &       & \gcm  &       &       &       \\
\qty{51}{\%} attack
        &       & \gcm  &       & \gcm  &       &       \\
Pool hopping attack
        &       &       &       &       &       & \gcm  \\
% etc
Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS)
        &       &       & \gcm  &       &       &       \\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `tabularray` package. It's makes handling the style of the table easier. Here is an example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ninecolors}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Table cpation},
    label = {tab:long1}
]{
hlines, vlines,
colspec = {Q[3cm, l, m] *{6}{Q[2cm, c, m]}}, %1st column is 3cm and left aligned, all other 6 columns are centered
rows = {bg=black, fg=white, font=\small}, %black background, white text with small font size
rowhead = 1, %1st row will appear in every page
}
Head & Relatively long Head & Head & Head & Head & Head & Head\\ %This row will appear in every page
Hello & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Hello & Long Hello & More long Hello & Hello & Hello &\\
Hello &  & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello &\\
Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello &\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Notes:

- You may consider avoiding all vertical and most of the horizontal lines. It makes a table more professional.
- This table is wider than the textwidth. You may consider reducing column width.

Edit (according to OP's comment): If by the word compact, you mean to reduce the space between rows, then you may change that using the `rowsep` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ninecolors}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Table cpation},
    label = {tab:long1}
]{
% abovesep=0pt,%removes any vertical space above 
% belowsep=0pt,%removes any vertical space below
rowsep = 0pt, %removes any vertical space above and below.
hlines, vlines,
colspec = {Q[3cm, l, m] *{6}{Q[2cm, c, m]}}, %1st column is 3cm and left aligned, all other 6 columns are centered
rows = {font=\small}, %black background, white text with small font size
row{1} = {bg=black, fg=white},
rowhead = 1, %1st row will appear in every page
}
Head & Head & Head & Head & Head & Head & Head\\ %This row will appear in every page
Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello &\\
Hello &  & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello &\\
Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello &\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, what about the table I showed in my **desired** example? I only want the top columns black, with white text. The table to be more compact. How, can this be achieved with a *longtable* and ensuring it is compact?

Comment: If you want to color only the first row, then write `rows={font=\small},` and `row{1} = {bg=black, fg=white}`. Put comma after every line. And what do you mean by the word compact? I don't get it. Do you mean to reduce the space/separation between rows?

Comment: Imran, can this be achieved: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwyL8.png, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this can be achieved. I have added another code (just some modification of the first one). You may use this as a template and insert the content of your original table.